# Not able to create database using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use code-first approach of Entity Framework in my asp.net mvc application. Below is my connection string which was autogenerated...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Whenever I press F5, the following error occurs:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

What am I doing wrong??

I have SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition installed. I am trying to connect to SQL Server using Windows authentication. I am also following a video tutorial so there may not be anything wrong with code

Comment: This may not be answer but I am using visual studio 2010 and sql server 2008 whereas I was using EntityFramework 6.1.1 . This is compatible with sql server 2012. In sql server 2012 there is a new feature added called localdb. I read the last line of error and figured it. Hope this helps someone.....

Answer (score 2):

IF you have SQL Server **Enterprise** edition, you most likely won't have it installed as `SQLEXPRESS` instance (that's the default for the SQL Server **Express** installations that come with Visual Studio).

More likely than not, you have the unnamed *default* instance - so try to use this connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ApplicationServices" 
        connectionString="data source=.;Database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Not sure if your application really uses the `ApplicationServices` connection string - if not, adapt the one your app is using! Also, you'll need to replace the `YourDatabaseName` with the actual database name that you're using in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to an instance of SQL server that's installed on your machine, you'll want to use a connectionString formatted to use that instead. Your current connectionString is trying to create a database file from which to work, rather than building a database in your SQL server instance.

Try something like this;

`connectionString="data source=localhost;user id=<user with dbo access>;password=<user password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: I will add that I've never used code-first before, and there might be extra information that code-first requires in the connectionString. It's possible that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575976/sql-server-2008-connection-string-for-entity-framework-4-1-code-first) may help you.